# Flutter - Image Picker not Working After Installing in Real Device

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

My Image Picker Working Fine In Emulator 7 In Debug Mode in my Real Device But Not Working After Exporting App In my Real Device..

I am using this [plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker)

What's the problem see in this video:
[Video in Google Drive:](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DijHKvuAw_KfJxPsfMw-ilLj5BVDu3BF/view?usp=drivesdk)

In Debugging Where All things working fine:

[video in google drive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1E1bKQgmWTSlf1a2ZJ3Z_yACw0XXduUZR/view?usp=drivesdk)
as you can see every-thing is working fine in debug mode

This is my Image Picking Function

```
 File userAvatar;
 File get getUserAvatar => userAvatar;
 Future pickUserAvatar(BuildContext context, ImageSource source) async {
    final pickedUserAvatar = await picker.getImage(source: source);
    BotToast.showText(text: 'my picked name is $source');
    pickedUserAvatar == null
        ? BotToast.showText(text: 'Select Image')
        : userAvatar = File(pickedUserAvatar.path);

    userAvatar != null
        ? Provider.of<LandingService>(context, listen: false)
            .showUserAvatar(context)
        : BotToast.showText(text: 'Image Upload Error');

    notifyListeners();
  }
```

This is my show user Avatar Function Where i show after image Successfully picked

```
  showUserAvatar(BuildContext context) {
    return showModalBottomSheet(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.45,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 150.0),
                    child: Divider(
                      thickness: 4.0,
                      color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                    ),
                  ),
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 80.0,
                    backgroundColor: constantColors.transperant,
                    backgroundImage: FileImage(
                      Provider.of<LandingUtils>(context, listen: false)
                          .userAvatar,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Container(
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                      children: [
                        MaterialButton(
                          child: Text(
                            'Reselect',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                              decorationColor: constantColors.whiteColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Provider.of<LandingUtils>(context, listen: false)
                                .pickUserAvatar(context, ImageSource.gallery);
                          },
                        ),
                        MaterialButton(
                          color: constantColors.blueColor,
                          child: Text(
                            'Confirm Image',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: constantColors.whiteColor,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Provider.of<FirebasessOperations>(context,
                                    listen: false)
                                .uploadUserAvatar(context)
                                .whenComplete(() => {
                                      signUpSheet(context),
                                    });
                          },
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: constantColors.blueGreyColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
            ),
          );
        });
  }
```

I also add this line in my android manifest

> ```
> android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is your build Gradle version
go to android/build.grale

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.4'
```

hope it works,

Comment: Thanks, it's working can you tell me why this problem come?

Comment: not sure why this happened, but some of the official plugins don't work with ```classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0' ```, and this change is required for releasing.

Comment: It really solved my problem and change my app size from 80MB to 40MB. why?

Comment: this is not a solution as of 2022

Answer (score 1):

you need to check and grant user permission first before executing the photo selection function
kindly take a look at this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler
example:

```
// request a user for permission first 
Map<Permission, PermissionStatus> statuses = await [
  Permission.storage,
  Permission.camera,
].request();

 if (await Permission.storage.request().isGranted) {
   // Either the permission was already granted before or the user just granted it you 
   can now select photo.
 }
```